# Is unary machine code a concept?

Tags: communication-complexity

Please assume for the sake of this session that humans can fluently read and understand *machine languages* and time isn't a problem in that regard.

I, not a computer scientist, would at least theorize that a unary machine language is possible but might just be much "less comfortable" than binary machine language.

Is unary machine code a concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could express machine code in unary.  How do I know?  Well, anything that can be represented in binary, can be represented in unary.  Machine code can be represented in binary (as a binary string of bits)... therefore it can be represented in unary (as a unary string).

It wouldn't be useful or practical to do so.  It's not just less comfortable; it's much worse than that.  Conversion to unary involves an exponential increase in size (a string that takes $n$ bits in binary would take $2^n$ symbols in unary), so it would be totally infeasible in practice.  But in theory, you can imagine it; there's no barrier in principle.

Comment: Thank you so much for the nice accessible answer which sadly I cannot upvote; I wonder how worse it can be, what can be the most elementary/easy/primal example for how worse it can be... For example, let us take the smallest bit string of `01`; How long and tiring could it be in unary? (I hope it's not too long for this comment window)

Comment: @George, see edited answer.  $2^n$, for an $n$-bit string.  Machine code typically has $n$ in the millions, so exponentiating that gives you a ridiculously large number.

Comment: so for 4 bits it would be 2<sup>4</sub> as in 2*2*2*2? Sorry, I didn't work with power a long time.

Comment: @George, for 4 bits, it would be about $2^4=16$ symbols in unary.  For instance, the number 13 is 1101 in binary, or 1111111111111 in unary (13 1's).

Comment: How do you know where the unary encoding ends, though? Self-terminating codings for non-singleton alphabets are straight-forward, but to put a unary input on a Turing Machine's tape, you need one other symbol ("blank").